# What is the different between these structs identifiers

Tags: ios, swift

The below 2 structs are the same with the exception of how they generate the identifier.  Could you please explain what the difference is? If I use the first, my UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource works as expected (no scrolling on update).  If I use the second, the diffable will scroll.

```
struct PostDetail {
    var comment: Comment
    var like: CommentLike?
    var user: User

}

extension PostDetail: Hashable {
    var identifier: UUID {
       return UUID()
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        return hasher.combine(identifier)
    }
    
    public static func == (lhs: PostDetail, rhs: PostDetail) -> Bool {
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }
}

struct PostDetail {
    let identifier = UUID()
    var comment: Comment
    var like: CommentLike?
    var user: User

}

extension PostDetail: Hashable {
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        return hasher.combine(identifier)
    }
    
    public static func == (lhs: PostDetail, rhs: PostDetail) -> Bool {
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }
}
```

Comment: The first one is invalid, because it just generates a new and different UUID every time anyone asks for its identifier. The UUID is only a valid identifier if it is constant for the "same" instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand on what I've said in my comment and Rob Napier has said in his answer:

In your first struct, `identifier` is merely a *function* that generates a totally new value every time it is called. So it is never the same twice! Let's try it. Here's a reduced version of your struct:

```
struct PostDetail : Equatable {
    var identifier: UUID {
        return UUID()
    }
    static func ==(lhs:PostDetail, rhs:PostDetail) -> Bool {
        lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }
}
```

Let's test it:

```
let p = PostDetail()
p.identifier // 3FFE9C66-5B80-4EF4-95EC-50388D35040B
p.identifier // 2D180097-CFAC-47E9-8530-C3BD3D39F433
```

So its "identifier" is not a constant; just the opposite, it is constantly *changing*. But you can't "identify" anything that way. Any attempt at defining Equatable based on that will fail, because no two PostDetail objects can *ever* be equal, even if they are *the same* object!

```
let p2 = PostDetail()
p2 == p2 // false
```

Similarly your Hashable will always fail, in the sense that no two PostDetail objects will fall into the same hash bucket, not even two instances of the *same* object.

To be an identifier, a UUID *must* be constant. In your second struct, we see this line:

```
let identifier = UUID()
```

That is a constant. It is generated when the instance is created and it never changes (because `let`). *That* is how a UUID needs to behave.

So, you may seem to be working around some sort of animation "glitch", but you are doing so in a totally illegal and nonsensical way. There is no animation, I presume, because every PostDetail is "different" from every other, including itself. The *entire* diffable datasource content is being replaced, so there is nothing to animate (or something like that). You may be avoiding some interface behavior you don't like, but you are just fooling yourself, like someone who puts black tape over a car dashboard warning light.

Comment: Minor nit: You say "In your first struct, identifier is merely a function that generates a totally new value..." It's a computed property, which Swift treats differently than a function. You could certainly argue that a computed property is a lot like a function since it executes code and returns a new value, but the Swift language makes a distinction between the two.

Comment: @DuncanC I don't agree. A read-only computed property is nothing but its getter function.

Comment: "You may be avoiding some interface behavior you don't like, but you are just fooling yourself, like someone who puts black tape over a car dashboard warning light." Haha that is exactly what I have been doing! I have changed it to be correct as you have suggested, also my scrolling issue was to do with the composition layout estimated height being too small for a lot of my cells.  The issue I face now is as soon as the collection view loads, one of the cells show up quite large, but once I scroll it corrects itself, so need to fix that! P.S I have several version of your Programming iOS books

Answer (score 1):

The code in the first example is almost certainly wrong:

```
var identifier: UUID {
   return UUID()
}
```

This creates a new identifier every time you access it, which is the opposite of "an identifier." The second example is correct.